# Exporting poses in blender

Tags: export, pose-mode

I am having issues with exporting a model from blender.

I have a model and an animation linked together and I want to export an .obj or .stl model of the last frame of the animation (preferably in high detail).

The issues is that when I change the pose of the last frame (which I need to do to fix the model so that it looks right), the edit I do to the pose goes away as soon as I change keyframe or export as an .obj.

I read that I might have to change the rest pose but I couldn't manage to do that. Also how can I export the final .obj file in higher quality, as at the moment it exports as a very low-poly model and looks like rubbish.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should apply all the modifiers in the properties panel before exporting (starting from the upper, down to the lower).

If you want to export also the armature, after you applied the armature modifier to the mesh, go to pose mode and "apply pose as rest pose". Notice that this operation will destroy your animation (except for the last frame, that becomes the new "rest pose".